# Integrating a surface bound by a circle

Tags: integration

I'm having an issue setting up this problem correctly, regardless of how I seem to do it I end up canceling everything out and getting $0$, which isn't the correct answer.

$$
\text{Find the surface area of the part of the plane } 3x+2y+z=5\\\text{ that lies inside the cylinder }x^2 +y^2 = 4
$$

The region is a circle with radius 2. Because integrating from -2 to 2 will yield 0, I attempted to integrate the first quadrant and multiply it by four to get the whole area. I get the integrand by treating $z$ as the height and the implicit function of $f(x,y)$

$$
\begin{align}
4 \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{2}3x+2y-5\:dxdy\\
4 \int_{0}^{2} [\frac{3}{2}x^2+2yx-5x]_{0}^{2}\:dy\\
4 \int_{0}^{2} 4y - 4\:dy\\
16 [\frac{y^2}{2} - y]_0^2\\
\text{Which yields }0\text{.}
\end{align}
$$

Can someone tell me what I'm not doing correctly, because from my perspective it isn't immediately obvious what is wrong.

Comment: The area of the circle inside the cylinder in the $ \ xy-$plane is $ \ 4\pi \ $ , but the given plane is tilted with respect to that, so the portion of the plane asked about is a long ellipse.  You want to include the "projection factor" for a plane with a normal vector $ \ \langle \ 3, \ 2, \ 1 \ \rangle \ $ .

Comment: Doing a quick sanity check, your integral looks more like a volume than a surface area.  It looks like you are integrating $-z$ times the differential of area ($dx dy$) in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Having a chance to come back and read this further... you do not want to integrate the expression for $ \ z \ $ over the circle (which is not correct here) over the circle, as that would give you a volume.   You need to look at the expression for using a surface integral to find a bounded area on the plane.

Comment: We would conventionally integrate over the circle in the $ \ xy-$ plane and apply the projection factor, as the answer now posted suggests.  In this case, that factor is a constant, so you could integrate just one quadrant _in this case_.  In general, things get a little more involved...

Comment: I think it's possible to generalize this a bit more to the surface area of any plane that lies inside an ellipse or circle with $S = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{R}\sqrt{Q}} \sqrt{z_z^2+z_x^2+z_y^2} r \hspace{.1cm} dr \hspace{.05cm} d\theta= RQ \hspace{.05cm} \pi \sqrt{z_z^2+z_x^2+z_y^2}$ with the ellipse or circle of the form $\frac{(x+h)^2}{R^2}+\frac{(y+k)^2}{Q^2} = 1$ and we take the circle just to be a special case of this with $Q = R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler with cylindrical coordinates. We can state this surface area neatly as:

$\begin{align}
S &= \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{R} \sqrt{z_z^2+z_x^2+z_y^2} r \hspace{.1cm} dr \hspace{.05cm} d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^2 \sqrt{3^2+2^2+1^2}r \hspace{.1cm} dr \hspace{.05cm} d\theta \\
&= \sqrt{14} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^2  r \hspace{.1cm} dr \hspace{.05cm} d\theta \\
&= 4\pi \sqrt{14} 
\end{align}$

(Where $z_z, z_x$ and $z_y$ are the coeffeicents $z, x$ and $y$. And $R$ is the radius of the given circle.)

Comment: I keep seeing your username pop-up, and I can't tell you how appreciative I have been of your help. I should have taken this summer semester off instead of trying to do as much as I have while working and dealing with my depression. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to help, and by the way the normal vector business Reckless was referring to is essentially what we are doing above, thinking of projecting that normal vector onto the circle in the plane is the same kind of logic.